# File sharing with Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: files, backup, cloud, sharing, storage

I have setup Ubuntu 12.04 Server and am using it as a raid 1 backup for all my photos and files. I would like to set up a web based file server and backup like Google Drive so I can share my files and get to them whenever I need to. I want it to be easy to get to with no extra programs to install. Like I said, just like Google Drive. I've looked all over for solutions, but I don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated. I don't mind trying to implement it myself, I just need to know where to start looking!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a private cloud type offering... something like [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) or [Kolab](https://kolab.org/overview) would do the trick.